# how to get all of facebook public profile's posts with graph api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm in a middle of a project that examines a profile whole posts, but i can't get them because the maximum limit of the posts is 100 and i need more than that.
when i try to get more than 100 posts it returns:

```
"error": {
"message": "(#100) The 'limit' parameter should not exceed 100",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "FEQyL7CKvLO"
}
```

Anyone knows how to bypass this problem and get more than 100 posts?
Also is there a way to know exactly how much posts did a public profile post? so I can send a request for the exact number of posts that I need (after I'll know how to solve my first problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use paging. The limit is not the overall limit, but the limit of posts per page. You can simply go to the next page and fetch the next 100 posts.

Check the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging